# Jasmine - Mocked method can't be found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

In a Jasmine test I have the following:

```
CommentMock = function() {};
CommentMock.prototype.save = function() {
  // stuff
};
spyOn( CommentMock.prototype, 'save' ).andCallThrough();
```

However, I'm getting this error:
`Failure/Error: save() method does not exist`

In an Angular controller I have this:

```
$scope.newComment = new Comment();

$scope.processComment = function( isValid ) {
  if ( isValid ) {

    Comment.save( $scope.newComment )
      .$promise
      .then(
        function() {
          // success stuff
        },
        function() {
          // error junk
        }
      );
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you show comment? is this a service? If so it returns an object not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Comment is a service I would mock it like this instead:

```
CommentMock = {}
CommentMock.save = function() {
  // stuff
};
spyOn( CommentMock, 'save' ).andCallThrough();
```

But actually I wouldnt mock it like this at all. I would allow the service to be injected into the unit test and then intercept the service call using the spyOn method of jasmine.

```
var Comment, $rootScope, $controller; //... maybe more...

beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _Comment_, _$controller_ //,... everything else) {
  $controller = _$controller_;
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  Comment = _Comment_;
}));

function setupController() {

  spyOn(Comment, 'save').andCallThrough();

  controller = $controller('YOURCONTROLLERSNAME', {
   $scope: $scope,
   Comment: Comment 
  }

}
```

Code is super simplified and wont work straight like this but its the overall idea...

Some other unit testing links I wrote:

[Mocking Controller Instantiation In Angular Directive Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029502/mocking-controller-instantiation-in-angular-directive-unit-test)

[Unit testing in AngularJS - Mocking Services and Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830391/unit-testing-in-angularjs-mocking-services-and-promises)

Comment: I thought your first suggestion would work at first too, but then `$scope.newComment = new Comment();` no longer works, because CommentMock isn't an object constructor. Injecting the actual service, Comment, works, but I thought because I'm writing unit tests, they should be as isolated as possible. Shouldn't dependencies be mocked or stubbed generally?

Comment: we are mocking them, but through controlling what they return. This is the approach we have been using now where I work for the last few months with Angular unit testing. Why recreate the code you would like to use in a test - test the original code!

Comment: Also when you are testing a controller which I assume you are you are not concerned with the functionality of the Comment service - this is tested elsewhere and assumed to be workign correctly when you inject it into a controller to use.

Comment: That makes sense. I changed the `andCallThrough()` to `andCallFake()` so I can mock the async functionality without relying on the Comment service. Thanks a lot! That helped a bunch!

Comment: No worries dude! I have written a few different questions and answers on unit testing best ideas... I will put the links in my answer